# Implement installable themes for Android app

Tags: android, themes, android-contentprovider, app-themes

As there is no official solution for this one, I'm relying to you dev who already done it

I would like to implement an "install theme from Play Store and apply it to my app" :

1. The user install my app
2. He browse for theme specific to my app on the Play Store (or free in app) and install it
3. Then he apply it to the app

To illustrate the goal : [Beautifull Widgets](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.levelup.beautifulwidgets.free) has done it, you install the widgets and you can download theme to apply

My first thought is to go with [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html) so the theme will just provide the elements to the app

But I don't know if it's the best way to do it ? What's your thoughts ?